# NginX strip custom host header

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Let me start of by stating our problem. We have some legacy applications. Those applications on multiple occasions read the Host header send by the user and create hyperlinks or do other logic based on the host header. This  would allow users to create links to our website with our website linking back to any host.

Our solution is to validate the Host header in NginX. Or rather set the host header to the requested url.

Example:
user performs curl like the following:

```
curl foo.bar.com -H 'Host: danger.com'
```

Currently our applications would receive the host as "danger.com". In NginX we want to overwrite this host header to "foo.bar.com"

In NginX we can of course set the host header for a server in the following way.

```
server {
      server_name ~^((foo|lorem|ipsum)\\.)?bar\\.com$
      proxy_set_header Host foo.bar.com
}
```

The obvious problem here would be that this only works for 1 of our subdomains.

Now we have reached my question. Is there a way to set the host header to the requested host in NginX? Or are there any other ways to remedy this problem. Looking through the NginX global variable list I could not find any available variable for the user requested host.

Comment: Every HTTP header can be accessed via [`http_<header>`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) nginx variable. Variable you want to check is `$http_host`.